# Movie where two spies are returning home, but have a virus that the enemy put on them as a weapon

Tags: story-identification, movie, virus

I am trying to find this movie I watched a long long time ago. The basics of what I remember:

1. the US (or the "West") is at war with China (or some Eastern power)
2. it was set in the future, something like the 2060s
3. movie was probably made in 70s or 80s
4. two spies are returning home from a mission, but they have some sort of accident and get frozen to be treated later
5. they spend a few days frozen, then are thawed and cured, and it turns out one of them is a double agent, and is carrying a virus that is meant to wipe the West in 14 days

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, I found the movie with the help of ChatGPT. The movie is called *[Project X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_X_(1968_film))*, it's from 1968, directed by William Castle.

[image: Film poster for *Project X]

> Hagen Arnold (Christopher George) is an American spy in the year 2118. The geopolitical climate of Earth has changed significantly over the years with Sino-Asia (China) being the only other superpower and enemy of the United States. Overpopulation is a looming issue. On a covert mission to Sino-Asia, Arnold sends a message to his handlers in the U. S. stating that "The West will be destroyed in fourteen days". Prior to the mission, he had been injected with an anti-torture drug which is triggered by extreme pain. The extreme pain will erase his mind, making it impossible for him to reveal anything to his torturers. Hagen is safely brought back to the USA and placed in cryogenic preservation until the government can devise a way to get the information out of him. With the key to discovering the secret weapon the Sino-Asians were working on locked inside his mind the American scientists resort to using a holographic memory reading device that can see inside his mind while he is asleep. The scientists also create an elaborate historical reenactment of the 1960s (Arnold has a history degree centered on this tumultuous decade) as a means to create a role-playing mechanism that may coax the information to the surface of the unsuspecting Arnold. To keep his suspicions down in the 1960s mock-up, they also create a 1960s personality matrix to implant in his mind. He is led to believe he is a criminal hiding out at a farmhouse and cannot leave lest he be arrested.

....

> The memory viewing and holographic machinery unleashes a mental power in Hagen. The mental power creates an energy field that kills Gallea in a spectacular display of light and fury. His death however becomes the key the scientists were looking for. They extract Gallea's brain from his body, and, while keeping it alive in a nutrient tank, perform the same brain reading exercise on it as they did with Hagen. Gallea's memories show how the Sino-Asians plan on destroying the West. Gallea injected Hagen Arnold with a myriad of medieval diseases which will, in fourteen days, make him a living plague bomb capable of spreading the diseases throughout the U. S., thus effectively destroying it from within.

### Trailer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: And don't forget to accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: This is the first time i have seen ChatGpt correctly identifying something posted on this site.